# Merging images in UWP

Tags: windows, mobile, bitmap, merge, uwp

I'm drawing some lines in an InkCanvas which I'm converting to a BitmapImage. I want to merch this image with another BitmapImage, but I can't find any way to do this in UWP. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your needs, Lumia Imaging SDK might be interesting to you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use WriteableBitmap with [WritieableBitmapEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx/) instead of BitmapImage. Then simply use WriteableBitmap's new [Blit()](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branches/WBX_1.0_WinMD/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapBlitExtensions.cs) function with None as BlendMode and you should have the desired effect.

Comment: I end up with images that look like this http://imgur.com/JUN0lVJ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Woah, that looks very very strange. My first guess is that you are creating the WriteableBitmaps incorrectly. How do the images look before you make the merge? How do you create WriteableBitmaps from them? Could you show some code for the latter please?